# File Upload in Angular 4

Tags: angular, file-upload, dependencies, peer

when I'm trying to install
    "npm install ng2-file-upload --save" 
in my angular 4 application it throws

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @4.1.0
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @4.1.0
`-- ng2-file-upload@1.2.1
```

and upload is not working 
my applications throws

"Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'input'"

this is **my HTML**

```
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="upload" multiple formControlName="file" id="file"/>
```

and its **Component**

```
import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';   
import { FileSelectDirective, FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-
upload';

export class PersonalInfoComponent implements OnInit
{
    public upload:FileUploader= new FileUploader({url:""});
}
```

**Parent Module**

```
import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

@NgModule({

imports: [
..
....
..
FileUploadModule
],

export class RegistrationModule { }
```

and I didn't Import/change anything in AppModule(Grand Parent Module).

***can someone help me on this please...***

Answer (score 4):

**Upload images in Angular 4 without a plugin**
This is the article that might be worth trying.
[Upload images in Angular 4 without a plugin](http://www.bentedder.com/upload-images-angular-4-without-plugin/)

It emphasize on these points:

1. Using the .request() method instead of .post
2. Sending formData straight into the body.
3. Customizing header items and constructing a new RequestOptions
   object.
4. In order to send formData with image content you must remove the Content-Type header.

Comment: Nice article! It helped.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think we need some extra libraries

```
onFileChange(event){
   let files = event.target.files; 
   this.saveFiles(files);
    }
@HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) onDragOver(event) {
    this.dragAreaClass = "droparea";
    event.preventDefault();
}
@HostListener('dragenter', ['$event']) onDragEnter(event) {
    this.dragAreaClass = "droparea";
    event.preventDefault();
}
@HostListener('dragend', ['$event']) onDragEnd(event) {
    this.dragAreaClass = "dragarea";
    event.preventDefault();
}
@HostListener('dragleave', ['$event']) onDragLeave(event) {
    this.dragAreaClass = "dragarea";
    event.preventDefault();
}
@HostListener('drop', ['$event']) onDrop(event) {   
    this.dragAreaClass = "dragarea";           
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    this.saveFiles(files);
}
```

And now we are ready to upload files with drag and drop as well as by clicking the link button and upload extra data with files.

See the complete article here [Angular 4 upload files with data and web api by drag & drop](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1218/angular-4-upload-files-with-data-and-web-api-by-drag-drop)

Answer (score 2):

For common solution is to create new module like `shared module`. You just need create shared module like
this and import shared module in `app.module` file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { FileSelectDirective, FileDropDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

@NgModule({
     imports: [ FileUploadModule],  
     declarations: [ ],
     exports :[ FileSelectDirective, FileDropDirective, FormsModule,
               FileUploadModule],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

just import share.module in your app.module like this.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule} from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [SharedModule],
    declarations: [],
    exports :[],
   })
export class AppModule { }
```

take a look on lazy loading in angular 4

Comment: Try to do this but got this error, Type FileSelectDirective is part of the declarations of 2 modules: FileUploadModule and PackagesModule! Please consider moving FileSelectDirective to a higher module that imports FileUploadModule and PackagesModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes FileSelectDirective then import that NgModule in FileUploadModule and PackagesModule.

Comment: I think your are using the file select directive in 2 modules, and which version your are using for ng2-file-upload.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an external library to do this, check below sample code

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: '<div>'
        + '<input type="file" (change)="upload($event)">'
        + '</div>',
})

export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private _service: commonService) { }

    upload(event: any) {
        let files = event.target.files;
        let fData: FormData = new FormData;

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fData.append("file[]", files[i]);
        }
        var _data = {
            filename: 'Sample File',
            id: '0001'
        }

        fData.append("data", JSON.stringify(_data));

        this._service.uploadFile(fData).subscribe(
            response => this.handleResponse(response),
            error => this.handleError(error)
        )
    }
    handleResponse(response: any) {
        console.log(response);
    }
    handleError(error: string) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

[More info](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2018/01/file-upload-and-send-data-to-backend.html)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" id="file">
```

TS:

```
@Component({
  ......
})

export class myComponent{

    form: FormGroup;

    contructor(fb: FormGroup){
       form: fb.group({file: null});
    }

 //fVals comes from HTML Form -> (ngSubmit)="postImage(form.value)" 
    postImage(fVals){
      let body = new FormData();
      body.append('file', formValues.file);

      let httpRequest = httpclient.post(url, body);
      httpRequest.subscribe((response) =>{
         //..... handle response here
      },(error) => {
         //.....handle errors here
      });
   }

   onFileChange(event) {
     if(event.target.files.length > 0) {
       let file = event.target.files[0];
       this.form.get('file').setValue(file);
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import fileupload from primeng or use simple file uploader

**HTML**

```
  <p-fileUpload name="myfile[]"  customUpload="true" 
     (uploadHandler)="uploadSuiteForRelease($event)" auto="auto"></p-fileUpload>
```

**TS**

```
 var data = new FormData();
        let index: number = 0;
        if (this.files != undefined)
        {
            for (let file of this.files.files)
            {
                data.append("myFile" + index, file);
                ++index;
            }
        }
     data.append('viewModel', JSON.stringify(<<data model that needs to be 
     sent with request>>));
```

Send this data with request return this._httpClient.post('api/controller', data);

**Server**

```
  [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
        {
            HttpPostedFile httpPostedFile = null;
            var viewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReleasesViewModel>(HttpContext.Current.Request["viewModel"]);
            if (viewModel != null)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
                {
                    var cnt = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count;
                    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
                    {
                        httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["myFile" + i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```