# Spring Angular 4 upload image?

Tags: spring, angular, spring-data-jpa

How upload image with Angular 4 ?

```
<input type="file" (change)="uplod($event)"/>
```

Spring code :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Etablissement/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    File convertFile = new File("C:/Users/acer/reservationF/reservation/reservation/image"+file.getOriginalFilename());
    convertFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(convertFile);
    fout.write(file.getBytes());
    fout.close();
    return new ResponseEntity<>("File is uploaded successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993145/file-upload-in-angular-4)

Comment: Refer my answer from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279484/sending-file-object-to-spring-rest-controller-through-angular-5/48295301#48295301

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This worked for me. You don't have to import any external libraries for this method.

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx">

fileChange(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if(fileList.length > 0) {
        let file: File = fileList[0];
        let formData:FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
        let headers = new Headers();
        /** No need to include Content-Type in Angular 4 */
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        this.http.post(`${this.apiEndPoint}`, formData, options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log('success'),
                error => console.log(error)
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with some modification
[Angular 4 – Upload/Get MultipartFile to/from Spring Boot Server](http://javasampleapproach.com/frontend/angular/angular-4-uploadget-multipartfile-tofrom-spring-boot-server)